# Word(s) to describe an indirect boys club

Tags: phrase-requests

I can't think of word(s) to describe a twitter group of people who haven't met but have an indirect familiarity with each other. I thought of clique but it doesn't seem to fit a loose indirect group.

e.g.

> John hesitated to contribute to a twitter conversation on a technology subject as reading through the conversation it felt like an *exclusive boys club* and he was worried his contributing could make him see like an outsider which could tarnish his public image.

Background:
I find with twitter the people who converse with each other in conversations in a technical topic use humour or snappy one liners and have this unique language of their own. They have never met each other just follow each other due to a common interest. It is similar to a boys club or exclusive club but not really as they have never met in real life but follow each other so know the unique behavior and what twitter tweets the other would engage with. A new person wanting to give his insight in a current topic of conversation might ask a logical question but because it isn't in the same style, format or historical sequence the person is treated as an outsider or twitter shunned, excluded or treated as a person not part of the group in their tweet responses.

Comment: Just a note: calling it a "boys club" has the connotation that it is gender-segregated and that women cannot be part of it. That may or may not be the case for the group you're describing.

Comment: yes I want a gender neutral answer. I just used boys club as example as it is common used term

Answer (score 2):

In the second definition of [ingroup (or in-group)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/in-group?s=t) here, it seems to fit your definition pretty well:

> In-group
>
> 2. *Sociology*. a group of people sharing similar interests and attitudes, producing feelings of solidarity, community, and exclusivity.

Comment: That the thing with twitter. Your neither in nor out as all tweets are public for everyone on twitter. There is no exclusive club, its merely loosely connection of people who have commonality and have communicated previously

Comment: @devc2 The term doesn't necessarily imply privacy, just that they consider themselves a community. For instance, Congress would be an in-group, even though their deliberations are public.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [insiders](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insider) [MWD]

> a person recognized or accepted as a member of a group, category, or organization

vs

[outsiders](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outsider) [MWD]

> a person who does not belong to or is not accepted as part of a particular group or organization